# Finding paths from node A to node B using the given data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, search, tree

I am stuck with a tricky problem as I am not able to think in a recursive way to find a solution for it.

Here is my data structure:

```
public class Airport {
    String name;
    Set<Neighbour> neighbours;
    ...
}

public class Neighbour {
    Airport airport;
    double costToReach;
    ...
}
```

I am trying to get the available paths(list of list) from one `Airport` to another `Airport`.

```
List<List<Airport>> getPaths(Airport source, Airport destination) {
    // Logic goes here
}
```

Expected input sample:

```
Source airport - Mumbai
Destination airport - Delhi
```

Expected output sample:

```
Mumbai -> Pune -> Delhi
Mumbai -> Ahmedabad -> Noida -> Delhi
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a method that takes a starting point, a target point and a set of already visited airports. In this method, you can:

- Return the path if the starting point is the end point.
- Loop over all neighbors of the starting point minus all already visited airports and make a recursive call using the neighbor as the starting point and with the set of already visited airports plus the current starting point (make sure that you clone this set, or use a stack and restore its state after the recursive call).

If you do this, you effectively attempt every path from the given starting point to the given target point without visiting the same airport twice. I will leave the return value of this recursive method as an exercise for you (the return value has to be used to obtain the succesful paths that were found).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Python as I'm not versed in Java; but since you tagged the question with "algorithm," I think can be easily understood and converted.

```py
def getPaths(source, destination):
  # We’ve reached the destination
  if source["name"] == destination["name"]:
    # Return a list of lists
    return [[destination["name"]]]

  result = []

  # If there are no neighbours or
  # none of them yield a destination,
  # ‘result’ will be an empty list
  for neighbour in source["neighbours"]:
    paths = getPaths(neighbour, destination)
    result.extend([[source["name"]] + path for path in paths])

  return result
```

Example:

```
mumbai = {"name": "Mumbai"}
pune = {"name": "Pune"}
delhi = {"name": "Delhi"}
ahmedabad = {"name": "Ahmedabad"}
noida = {"name": "Noida"}

# Assign neighbours
mumbai["neighbours"] = [pune, ahmedabad]
pune["neighbours"] = [delhi]
delhi["neighbours"] = []
ahmedabad["neighbours"] = [noida]
noida["neighbours"] = [delhi]

print(getPaths(mumbai, delhi))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I couldn't wrap my head around this line `result.extend([[source["name"]] + path for path in paths])`, can you tell me what it does so that I could convert it to java.

Comment: Seems like you are doing a lot in this one line, it would be better if you break it into multiple lines so that I could understand easily.

Comment: Sure, `extend` is like `concat`. So it concatenates another list to whatever `result` is at that point. The list (or array) it is concatenating with `result` is a list of lists, where each one of lists is `[source["name"]] + path` so a list with the elements being the airport names in order.